# Generic Method with a Generic Class in c#

Tags: c#, generics, methods, abstract-class

I would like to know if there is a simple way in which I can simplify creating a Generic Method that takes a Generic Abstract Class.
It looks like this:

```
public J Read<T, M, J>(string fileName) where T : FileAccess<M, J> where M : Accessor where J : new() {
        /*More Code... return J*/
    }
```

The FileAccess Class takes the same generic "arguments".

```
public abstract class FileAccess<T, M> : IDisposable where T : Accessor where M : new() {/* More Code*/}
```

And there are other classes implementing this abstract class. e.g.

```
public class StateAccess : FileAccess<XMLAccessor, List<Data>> {/*More Code*/}
```

Most of the times C# is clever enough to figure it out the other generic types you're using, so you don't have to write them. I thought it would work the same and it would end up something like this:

```
Read<StateAccess>("state");
```

But instead this is what I have to do in order to make it work:

```
Read<StateAccess, XMLAccessor, List<Data>>("state");
```

Even though I already made a Class StateAccess that uses XMLAccessor and a List of Data.

The Method Read will be used with other classes that inherits from FileAccessor.
So my question is: How can I make my code work so I end up with this?

```
Read<StateAccess>("state");
Read<OtherAccess>("otherFileName");
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I don't think it's poosible. In C# you have to either declare _all_ generic arguments or _none_ (if the compiler can infer _all_ arguments by itself). To declare only a subset of the required arguments is not allowed in c#.

Comment: Oh well, that's sad news. Is there any way to change the method so it knows the generic must be a non-abstract class and that the class is a non-generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

René's comment is correct- you cannot infer a subset of generic arguments here.

What you can do (assuming that your method `Read` doesn't do anything with the generic type `M`) is something like this:

```
interface IReadableFileAccess<J> { ... // methods that Read needs... }
```

Then make `FileAccess` or `StateAccess` implement `IReadableFileAccess` and change the signature of `Read` to:

```
J Read<J>(IFileAccess<J> access, String fileName,  ... whatever ...) { ... }
```

To which you can just pass an instance of `StateAccess`, which is closed for `J`:

```
Read(someStateAccess, "fileName")
```

Note: "Closed for J" above means that StateAccess is not generic for J- the type for J is specified and therefore inferable.